In HIve, When I run select count(*) from table query, it does not run on TEZ but runs on MR
I am running a simple select count(*) from table and it fails when I run this over Tez engine.
While I run this same on MR engine it works.
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
This is the only error that comes out and no other information anywhere.
We Tried using "MR Engine" instead of "Tez Engine" and it failed.

Can you check the logs and share the full exception? It should be in either Hive's CLI or HS2 logs, depending on where you executed the command
